Возврат к нужной точке кода (python)
print ("Калькулятор для рассчёта ивентов и т.д.")
A = int (input('Выберите операцию:\n 1: Количество валюты для прохождения события  \n 2: Оставшееся количество опыта для исследования модуля/танка\n '))
if A == 1:
    print ("Вас приветствует калькулятор расчёта ивентов на победы в Tanks Blitz")
    A   = int (input ("Сколько валюты осталось до прохождения события? "))
    B = int (input ("Дополнительные бонусы в день: "))
    C = int (input ("Количество побед с бонусами в день: "))
    D = int (input ("Оставшаяся продолжительность события, полных дней: "))
    F = (A-B*C*D)
    print ("Вам понадобится сделать ещё", F+D , "побед, чтобы пройти данное событие")
    G = int (input ("Количество дней с учётом часов: "))
    import math
    H = math.ceil (F/G)
    print ("Количество побед в день, чтобы пройти событие:", H)
if A == 2:
    print ("Рассчёт оставшегося количества опыта для исследования модуля/танка")
    A = int (input ("Стоимость исследования модуля/танка: "))
    B = int (input ("Количество боевого опыта: "))
    C = int (input ("Количество свободного опыта: "))
    D = (A-(B+C))
    print ("Тебе осталось", D , "опыта для исследования")

Приветствую. Что и как нужно использовать, чтобы после выполнения условия if == 1 или if == 2, можно было снова вернуться к выбору? Т.е.:
(Калькулятор для расчёта ивентов и т.д.
Выберите операцию:
1: Количество валюты для прохождения события
2: Оставшееся количество опыта для исследования модуля/танка
1
Вас приветствует калькулятор расчёта ивентов на победы в Tanks Blitz
Сколько валюты осталось до прохождения события?).
Например, я ошибся с выбором и хочу вернуться к выбору, используя команду "Назад".

Во первых, не переиспользовать переменные.
